# OpenCSV wrong date format

Tags: java, date, opencsv

I am using CsvToBean class of the openCSV. The bean has the date feild.

```
@CsvDate(value = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@CsvBindByPosition(position = 8)
private Date startDate;
```

I am doing the negative testing by passing the value "**2018-25-02**" but it is getting 
converted to **Thu Jan 02 00:00:00 GMT 2020** without throwing any issue.

Comment: Can you change `Date` to `LocalDate` from java-8?

Comment: It agrees: if you keep counting months, the 25th month of 2018 is the same as the 1st month of 2020. How to avoid OpenCSV accepting it I don’t know.

Comment: The `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` classes are both terrible, and both were replaced years ago by the *java.time* classes, by `Instant` and `LocalDate` respectively. See if OpenCSV has been updated to use *java.time*.

Comment: Also `LocalDate` will be sure to reject a 25th month any time, which can’t be said of all the old classes. So there may be a good solution for you there if it works.

Comment: Yes, I agree but openCSV doesn't support LocalDate :(

Answer (score 22):

You could create your own custom converter for java 8 LocalDate, e.g.

```
public class LocalDateConverter extends AbstractBeanField {
    @Override
    protected Object convert(String s) throws CsvDataTypeMismatchException, CsvConstraintViolationException {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        LocalDate parse = LocalDate.parse(s, formatter);
        return parse;
    }
}
```

Then you can just annotate your class like:

```
@CsvCustomBindByPosition(position = 8, converter = LocalDateConverter.class)
private LocalDate startDate;
```

Comment: Good Answer. For that particular format of YYYY-MM-DD, no need to specify a formatting. That standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format is parsed by default: `LocalDate.parse( "2019-01-23" )`

Comment: This is exactly what's I'm looking for.

Comment: IntelliJ gives a warning: "Raw use of parameterized class 'AbstractBeanField' ". Is there a cleaner way to do the same thing to avoid Raw Type?

Answer (score 22):

## OpenCSV 5

[OpenCSV 5.x onwards](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#upgrading_from_4_x_to_5_x) supports Java 8 java.time APIs natively.

To quote the documentation:

> Full support for the Java 8 Time API is included. Conversion to and from all JDK-types that implement [`TemporalAccessor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html) is included.

The following should therefore suffice:

```
@CsvDate(value = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@CsvBindByPosition(position = 8)
private LocalDate startDate;
```

Comment: I am trying to use it with `@CsvDate(value = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`, but I am getting `Unsupported field: InstantSeconds`.

Comment: Tom Carmi, you don't print the hour, minute and second of a LocalDate variable. Change LocalDate with LocalDateTime.

Comment: How to do this for the Instant object where the value being read in the CSV is a Long object time in ms since epoch